# Mediante el comando dotnet webapi, ¿existe un problema con la carpeta controllers?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Probando con versiones anteriores si me crea la carpeta de controllers, sin embargo, en la 8 no. ¿Hay algún cambio o alguna información que me puedan compartir?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según la documentación `dotnet new webapi --use-controllers -o TodoApi`. Agrega el comando de como lo creaste. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por comandos no tengo idea pero en Visual Studio, debes marcar la opción `Utilizar controladores`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas maneras puedes integrar controladores manualmente, para esto:

- Creas una carpeta llamada `Controllers`
- En el `program.cs` agregas:

  - `builder.Services.AddControllers();`
  - Y luego `app.MapControllers();`

Aquí el controller de ejemplo que trae la plantilla:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar `-controllers` para añadir los controladores. Entonces sería:

```
$ dotnet new webapi -controllers
```